# Facebook profile image is not updating via Cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cloudinary

I'm playing with Cloudinary and getting the Facebook profile image of a user. This is what I did:

1. I created a Cloudinary account (free)
2. I created a Facebook account (sample one without assign a profile image)
3. ** Works fine through my Rails app **
4. Then I changed the profile image of the user
5. Cloudinary still shows the user profile image as blank (4-5 days now)

This is my updated [Facebook sample](https://www.facebook.com/people/Gongale-Goda-Banda/100007103656209) user.

This is what I [get via Cloudinary](http://res.cloudinary.com/trymydish/image/facebook/100007103656209) (Ruby gem).

The problem is user's Facebook profile image is not updating via Cloudinary.

I'm using Cloudinary with Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary automatically refreshes Facebook profile pictures once a week, however you can explicitly refresh the image using the API, e.g.,

```
Cloudinary::Uploader.explicit("user_name", :type=>"facebook")
```

For more information:
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_image_upload#refresh_images

Note that Facebook is gradually changing its user IDs to be associated IDs by application rather than public IDs which they used till now.
It is on Cloudinary's road-map to support Facebook's new IDs convention.